# ContourListPlot not evaluating all of interpolated area

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I am trying to plot a contour for a matrix, but it seems not to be evaluating all the points. Here is the interpolated figure, followed by the MatrixPlot version itself. I used this colormap because otherwise it looks like the white parts are actually evaluated values, but here the white isn't in the colormap.

```
ListContourPlot[{{0.55, 0.62, 0.65, 0.668, 0.672, 0.67, 0.676, 0.67}, 
{0.56, 0.631, 0.659, 0.669, 0.673, 0.675, 0.677, 0.677}, 
{0.57, 0.637, 0.661, 0.671, 0.675, 0.675, 0.677, 0.677}, 
{0.6, 0.649, 0.665, 0.673, 0.675, 0.675, 0.677, 0.677},
{0.65, 0.669, 0.673, 0.675, 0.677, 0.677, 0.677,  0.677}, 
{0.71, 0.694, 0.685, 0.679, 0.677, 0.677, 0.677, 0.677},
{0.77, 0.718, 0.694, 0.683, 0.679, 0.677, 0.677, 0.677}, 
{0.807, 0.733, 0.7, 0.687, 0.681, 0.679, 0.677, 0.677},
{0.807, 0.7333, 0.7001, 0.68652, 0.6806, 0.67871, 0.67675, 0.67675}}, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

[image: ListContourPlot]  [image: ColorBar]

When I plot the data using MatrixPlot I get:

[image: MatrixPlot]

I have tried to change Method in ListContourPlot to different options without any sucess, but I'm not sure I understand the documentation for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListContourPlot[ m, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where `m` is your matrix